# Collision ImageViews not working

Tags: android, recursion, imageview, collision

I'm trying to generate random ImageViews on a Layout without the ImageViews intersecting each other. I'm generating a random point within the screen dimensions like this:

```
private Point generateRandomLocation(Point dimensions) {
    Random random = new Random();

    // generate random x
    int x = random.nextInt((dimensions.x - 0) + 1);

    // generate random y
    int y = random.nextInt((dimensions.y - 0) + 1);

    Point location = new Point(x, y);

    if(!collision(location)) {
        return new Point(x, y);
    } else {
        return generateRandomLocation(dimensions);
    }
```

}

The collision method contains the following method to determine wether the ImageViews collide or not. BubbleImage is a simple extension of ImageView.

```
private boolean collision(Point location) {
    // takes 100 as inital width & height
    int x_1 = location.x;
    int y_1 = location.y;

    int x_2;
    int y_2;

    boolean collided = false;

    // get all bubbleimages
    for (int i = 0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (childView instanceof BubbleImage) {
            x_2 = (int) childView.getX();
            y_2 = (int) childView.getY();

            // create rectangles
            Rect rect1 = new Rect(x_1, y_1, x_1 + 100, y_1 - 100);
            Rect rect2 = new Rect(x_2, y_2, x_2 + 100, y_2 - 100);
            collided = Rect.intersects(rect1, rect2);

        }
    }

    return collided;
```

}

Anyone spotting the faulty logic here?

Edit: Rect.intersects() seems to be returning false, even when the imageviews are intersecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating new Rects rect1 & rect2, the constructor is Rect(left, top, right, bottom). E.g. Rect(10, 10, 20, 20), because android screen origin is in the top left corner.
You have created the Rects in a wrong way, as Rect(left, **bottom**, right, **top**). Try switching the 2nd and 4th parameters in the constructor calls, or increase the 4th parameter to be bigger than 2nd.
Like this:
Rect rect1 = new Rect(x_1, y_1, x_1 + 100, y_1 **+** 100);